# Simple storing student info using struct programming

Tags: c

I have been learning C for a few week and came across a task of doing the following

1. Add student (through terminal, ask for a range of questions)
2. Delete last student (array of 5 student)
3. Display student list
4. Save student list to database (save in hard drive as a binary/text file)
5. Read the list from database
6. Exit the program

How should I approach this task and what kind of coding I should use for this?

Comment: At the end of a "pls send halp" trolling I think you're meant to add "kthxbai".

Comment: I think you would need a Switch-case based menus for developing a program like that. But you won't get much response unless you show us your efforts rather than asking for help straightaway.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Create a structure "Student".

Create method "display".

Take a look how you write/read to/from a file in C.

Implement a switch-case and call the methods you need for adding, deleting, displaying the list, writing/reading to/from file.

Here is some help to start:

```
struct Student{ //change it if you want
    char name[50];
    int year;
};

void display(int size, struct Student students[] ){
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        printf("%s: %d", students[i].name, students[i].year);
    }
}

int main(){
    struct Student students[5]; //this is the array you needed

    //more code here

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```